# How do cleanly initialize two structs in golang which depend on each other?

Tags: pointers, go, dependency-injection, interface

I've run into an issue in my current project where I have two modules, one implementing an interface for testing purposes, and one just a concrete struct, which each depend on a method from the other.

In order to resolve this tension, I've attempted to create a top-level "container" struct that holds a reference to the dependent struct and interface, and then with a method on the container struct, assign as a member of each component struct that top level container's pointer to the other struct. I am doing this instead of using globals in order to be able to better encapsulate my code for testing purposes.

However, it seems that whichever struct is initialized first does not see the change in the other struct's address when the second struct is initialized. I do not understand why, and I don't seem to be able to make this function as expected.

Since there are many extraneous details in the actual code I've created this toy example to illustrate what I'm talking about.

```
type container struct {
    r requestor
    a *A
}

type requestor interface {
    Request()
}

type A struct {
    r requestor
}

type R struct {
    a *A
}

func (r R) Request() {
    log.Info("I requested")
    return
}

func (container *container) NewA() *A {
    log.Info("New A received container.r: ", container.r)
    a := &A{
        r: container.r,
    }
    container.a = a
    return a
}

func (container *container) NewR() *R {
    r := &R{
        a: container.a,
    }
    container.r = r
    return r
}

func TestDepResolution(t *testing.T) {
    top := container{}

    top.NewR()
    top.NewA()

    // top.a.r = r

    log.Infof("top: %+v", top)
    log.Infof("R: %+v", top.r)
    log.Infof("A: %+v", top.a)

}
```

It's setup as a test so I can easily execute it within my project. The output is as such:

```
=== RUN   TestDepResolution
INFO[0000] New A received container.r: <nil>
INFO[0000] top: {r:0xc000010028 a:0xc00006abc0}
INFO[0000] R: &{a:0xc00006abc0}
INFO[0000] A: &{r:<nil>}
```

I expected that A's r variable would become equal to top's r variable after NewR() was called, but it doesn't seem to change. The same issue occurs the other way around if I switch the order of NewA() and NewR().

I expected since I am using pointers and interfaces here that the values would be connected when top's values changed, but it's apparent I must be misunderstanding something. I've tried playing around with the pointers quite a bit to no avail.

So why doesn't this work as I expected? Is there a way to make this work as I've proposed? Or am I thinking about this issue in an entirely wrongheaded way? I have tried to think about extracting functionality from the modules so that they are not mutually dependent and I could avoid this issue entirely, but I have not been able to come up with a good way to do so.

Comment: "one implementing an interface for testing purposes" This is your first problem: Introducing interfaces for testing purpose only is dangerous, especially if you intend to have just one implementation "and one just a concrete struct, which each depend on a method from the other." Consider to refactor this interface-for-testing-approach.

Comment: Why is the interface a problem here? Why would using an interface for testing be dangerous? It's my understanding that this is one of the key reasons to use an interface in the first place, and it has served me well so far. If you have an argument to the contrary I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to utilize pointers the way you seem to want to, you first need actual pointers (i.e. not `nil` pointers) and you also need to use pointer indirection to be able to "share" the updates to the pointed values.

For example:

```
type T struct { F string }

a := &T{"foo"} // non-nil pointer
b := a
fmt.Println(b) // output: {"foo"}

*a = T{"bar"}  // pointer indirection
fmt.Println(b) // output: {"bar"}
```

For comparison, here's what your code is attempting to do:

```
type T struct { F string }

a := (*T)(nil) // nil pointer
b := a
fmt.Println(b) // output: <nil>

a = &T{"bar"}  // plain assignment
fmt.Println(b) // output: <nil>
```

And note that even if you used pointer indirection, it is illegal to do so on a `nil` pointer and the runtime, if it encounters such an operation, will panic.

```
a := (*T)(nil) // nil pointer
b := a
fmt.Println(b) // output: <nil>

*a = T{"bar"} // pointer indirection on nil, will crash the program
fmt.Println(b)
```

So, your example doesn't work because it does not properly initialize the pointers and it does not use pointer indirection, rather, it uses simple assignment which just updates the target variable's pointer and not the pointed-to value.

---

To initialize the container properly you should do it in one step:

```
func NewContainer() *container {
    c := &container{a: &A{}}
    c.r = &R{a: c.a}
    c.a.r = c.r
    return c
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/hfbqJEVyAHZ

Or, if you *want* to do it in two, you can do something like this:

```
func (c *container) NewA() *A {
    log.Println("New A received c.r: ", c.r)
    a := &A{
        r: c.r,
    }
    if c.a != nil {
        *c.a = *a
    } else {
        c.a = a
    }
    return a
}

func (c *container) NewR() *R {
    if c.a == nil {
        c.a = new(A)
    }

    r := &R{
        a: c.a,
    }
    c.r = r
    c.a.r = r
    return r
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/krmUQOsACdU

but, as you can see, the multi step approach to initializing so tightly coupled dependencies can get unnecessarily convoluted and ugly, i.e. complex, i.e. very much error prone. Avoid it if you can.

---

All that said, personally, I would consider this kind of circular dependency a smell and would start thinking about redesign, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for clearing that up for me. I can see clearly now my mistakes in understanding of pointer indirection and nil pointers. Your example makes perfect sense and I like your suggestion of initializing in one step. The only issue I see is if both a and r become interfaces, c.a.r will not be directly modifiable here. Is my only option here to create a method on the interface, something like r.SetA() that reaches into the concrete object and sets the value properly sometime after both NewA and NewR have been called?

Comment: Also, agreed on the smell, but handling the awkward init seemed to be than refactoring away the circular dependency. A and R represent two modules that each keep state and respond to external events from different sources. Briefly, R needs to use A's methods to process the events it receives and formulate a response and A needs to refer to R's methods to enable R to send messages on its behalf. I feel certain that this must be a common issue in software, but I've not been able to resolve it myself. If you know of any good resources for learning how to resolve such a problem, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @DanielVeenstra https://play.golang.com/p/si_hyoa3Pap (same thing, just more verbose, more clear)

Comment: @DanielVeenstra it seems to me that you are in this situation because the modules run afoul of the Single Responsibility Principle, i.e. the modules are doing more than "one thing". To fix this you can split the modules until their individual parts do just one thing, which should, in practice, remove the circular dependency. Keep in mind that a smell indicates only a *possibility* of a deeper problem, i.e. it may be that the circular dependency in your case is the correct approach, usually it isn't, but sometimes it can't be helped. It's your code, you have to know, you have to decide.

Comment: @DanielVeenstra there are many books on design patterns that have good advice in them, but they also contain a lot of poison, I can't recommend any single one of those books. I also haven't read that much to be honest, so there may be books that are more than adequate for recommendation but I just haven't read those yet.

Comment: thank you for the example, makes perfect sense. Basically deal with only the concrete objects in the NewContainer initialization sequence and then only assign them as interfaces to container after they are fully set up.

Comment: I am sure that my modules violate the Single Responsibility Principle to some extent, probably due to the code's purpose sprawling over time. Knowing that I ultimately have to decide if this circular dependency is truly the correct approach, I am wondering if there is a principle to go by which helps identify when a circular dependency is truly the only correct option, and when it is just a byproduct of a mistaken design. I will certainly ponder on this as I examine my code.